# How to create multiple alerts for single resource in azure using terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

How to create multiple alerts for single resource in azure using terraform (i.e CPU, Memory & Disk I/O alerts of a VM)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this below code to create multiple alerts for single resource

```java
provider "azurerm"
features{}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rgv" {
  name     = "<resource group name>"
  location = "west us"
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "agv" {
  name                = "myactiongroup"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgv.name
  short_name          = "exampleact"
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "alert" {
  name                = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rgv.name
  scopes              = ["/subscriptions/1234XXXXXX/resourceGroups/<rg name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<virtualmachine name>"]
  description         = "description"
  target_resource_type = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
  
  criteria { 
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
    metric_name      = "Percentage CPU"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 80
  }
  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.agv.id
  }
}
```

***Reference:*** [hashicorp azurerm_monitor_metric_alert](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert)

Comment: Thank you for the response, but this is used for single metric value (CPU), I Wanted to add one more metric (RAM threshold, disk IOPS etc,) how to add those metrics in this code?